# Rotating a Square on Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, list, tkinter-canvas

I've got close, but there are two problems. One is the final position of the rotated square (no longer in centre). The second is my original vertices list mutates, in spite of my making a copy with list(..).

Any help much appreciated as usual.

```
from Tkinter import *
import math


WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400
CANVAS_MID_X = WIDTH/2
CANVAS_MID_Y = HEIGHT/2
SIDE = WIDTH/4

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, bg="black", height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

vertices = [
                    [CANVAS_MID_X - SIDE/2, CANVAS_MID_Y - SIDE/2],
                    [CANVAS_MID_X + SIDE/2, CANVAS_MID_Y - SIDE/2],
                    [CANVAS_MID_X + SIDE/2, CANVAS_MID_Y + SIDE/2],
                    [CANVAS_MID_X - SIDE/2, CANVAS_MID_Y + SIDE/2]]

def rotate(points, angle):
    new_points = list(points)
    rad = angle * (math.pi/180)
    cos_val = math.cos(rad)
    sin_val = math.sin(rad)
    for coords in new_points:
        x_val =  coords[0] 
        y_val = coords[1]
        coords[0] = x_val * cos_val - y_val * sin_val
        coords[1] = x_val * sin_val + y_val * cos_val
    return new_points

def draw_square(points):
    canvas.create_polygon(points, fill="red")

def test():
    print "vertices: ", vertices, "should be: ", "[[150, 150], [250, 150], [250, 250], [150, 250]]"


new_square = rotate(vertices, 30)
draw_square(new_square)
test()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining your problems clearly and posting a [mcve]!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first problem is that the formula you're using rotates around the origin. I assume you want to rotate the square around its center. To do that, you simply translate the square so its center is at the origin, rotate it, then translate it back.

The second problem is that doing `list(points)` *does* create a new outer list, but it *doesn't* create new lists for the lists inside `points`. There are ways to make a deep copy that creates new lists for those internal lists, but you don't really need to do that here. Just build a fresh list from the rotated vertices.

My version of your code draws the original square in blue so that we can see that the rotated square ends up in the correct location.

```
from Tkinter import *
import math

WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400
CANVAS_MID_X = WIDTH/2
CANVAS_MID_Y = HEIGHT/2
SIDE = WIDTH/4

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, bg="black", height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

vertices = [
    [CANVAS_MID_X - SIDE/2, CANVAS_MID_Y - SIDE/2],
    [CANVAS_MID_X + SIDE/2, CANVAS_MID_Y - SIDE/2],
    [CANVAS_MID_X + SIDE/2, CANVAS_MID_Y + SIDE/2],
    [CANVAS_MID_X - SIDE/2, CANVAS_MID_Y + SIDE/2],
]

def rotate(points, angle, center):
    angle = math.radians(angle)
    cos_val = math.cos(angle)
    sin_val = math.sin(angle)
    cx, cy = center
    new_points = []
    for x_old, y_old in points:
        x_old -= cx
        y_old -= cy
        x_new = x_old * cos_val - y_old * sin_val
        y_new = x_old * sin_val + y_old * cos_val
        new_points.append([x_new + cx, y_new + cy])
    return new_points

def draw_square(points, color="red"):
    canvas.create_polygon(points, fill=color)

def test():
    old_vertices = [[150, 150], [250, 150], [250, 250], [150, 250]]
    print "vertices: ", vertices, "should be: ", old_vertices
    print vertices == old_vertices

draw_square(vertices, "blue")

center = (CANVAS_MID_X, CANVAS_MID_Y)
new_square = rotate(vertices, 30, center)
test()
draw_square(new_square)

mainloop()
```

I've also made a few other minor changes to your code.

BTW, you probably should do

```
from __future__ import division
```

before your other imports. That tells Python to use true division. Without it, `SIDE / 2` does integer division. That works ok here, but it won't be correct if `SIDE` is an odd number.

---

You should try to get out of the habit of doing

```
from Tkinter import *
```

Instead, do

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

and then call the Tkinter functions like this:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="black", height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
```

This is slightly more typing, but it makes the code easier to read and maintain, and prevents the errors that can occur when your code accidentally uses one of the names that Tkinter has defined. FWIW, doing `from Tkinter import *` imports over 170 names into your namespace. You don't need that clutter!

Comment: Love it! Thanks. At this stage in my learning, this kind of "beyond the basics" answer is very useful indeed.

Comment: That is not rotating the square -- rather it is creating another square with rotated coordinates. It is not useful, e.g., when you want an animation where a square moves to a certain point, rotates and moves in another direction.

Comment: @Pagol Well, it's what Robin wanted. ;) If you have a new question about rotating a Tkinter Canvas object in the manner you describe then you should ask a new question (after first checking to make sure that such a question doesn't already exist, of course).

Comment: Rotating geometrical object should be very common operation, there should be some inbuilt function for this. If not, it need to be created and added in lib.